# What is a more formal alternative for saying where do you slack at and where do you excell at

Tags: phrase-requests

What is a more formal alternative for saying where do you slack at and where do you excell at

Comment: The expression 'arguments for and against' works for debates _and_ product reviews.

Comment: "Strengths and weaknesses" is another common synonym for "pros and cons."

Comment: "Pluses and minuses"

Answer (score 14):

Depending on the subject matter, the following pairs might work:

> Strengths and Weaknesses of ...
>
> Assets and Liabilities of ...
>
> Gains and Losses of ...
>
> Opportunities and Obstacles of ...

---

Some single word options:

> Evaluation of ...
>
> Appraisal of ...
>
> Assessment of ...

---

Arguments ***for*** and **against** seems like the formal alternative suggested by the definition and etymology of [pros and cons](http://www.wordreference.com/definition/pros%20and%20cons):

> pl n
>
> the various arguments in favor of and against a motion, course of
>   action, etc
>
> Etymology: 16th Century: from Latin prō **for** + con, from
>   contrā **against**

Depending on the actual context you could use a number of alternatives for [arguments](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/arguments?s=t):

> - I assessed the arguments *for and against...*
> - We investigated the claims *for and against...*
> - They considered the assertions *for and against...*
> - She examined the reasons *for and against...*
> - He evaluated the considerations *for and against...*

Credit to Edwin Ashworth for his comment.

Answer (score 4):

"Advantages and Disadvantages" seems like an obvious choice, however depending on the actual title of your paper you may prefer using "Positive Effects and Negative Effects of..." (if it's a scientific paper)